# How to prevent time overlap for the same date?

Tags: mysql, date, time, coldfusion, overlap

I'm working on project where I have to prevent time overlap for the same date. User have to pick Pick Date, Drop Date, Pick Time and Drop Time. My logic works fine and prevents time overlapping but I'm trying to figure it out how I can allow the user to pick the the same date and then compare the time. Here is my HTML code:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <label>Pick up Date</label>
    <input name="DateFrom" id="DateFrom" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" value="">
    <label>Pick up Time</label>
    <input name="TimeFrom" id="TimeFrom" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" value="">
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
   <label>Drop off Date</label>
   <input name="DateTo" id="DateTo" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" value="">
   <label>Drop off Time</label>
   <input name="TimeTo" id="TimeTo" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" value="">
  </td>
</tr>
```

and here is my logic with passed arguments:

```
<cfargument name="DateFrom" type="string" required="yes">
<cfargument name="DateTo" type="string" required="yes">
<cfargument name="TimeFrom" type="string" required="yes">
<cfargument name="TimeTo" type="string" required="yes">

<cfquery name="qryTest">
   Select PickDate,DropDate,PickTime,DropTime
   From ptReservation
   Order by PickDate
</cfquery>

<cfif (arguments.TimeTo LT qryTest.PickTime OR qryTest.DropTime LT arguments.TimeFrom)>
    <cfquery name="addReservation" datasource="testData">
       //Do insert
    </cfquery>
</cfif>
```

So for example my code will prevent and time overlaps, but what if time is not at the same date. How I can check first if dates are matching and then check time overlap? if anyone can help with this please let me know.

Comment: A good place to start is with the Functions by Category view in the documentation. Specifically, [date functions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1a60c-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6986). There are several that can be used to compare dates.  RE: `<cfargument  type="string" ...` Side note, be sure to validate the input values are indeed validate dates and times. Relying on CF's implicit conversion may not throw an error, but it may not produce the expected results either...

Comment: If I'm correct in assuming that the Pickup Time occurs on the Pickup Date (and the Drop Time occurs on the Drop Date), then you should be combining each time with its date before comparing Pickup and Drop to each other.

Comment: From where does qryTest come?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: *How I can check first if dates are matching* Change the query to retrieve records for the selected date. However, as Dan mentioned on your other thread, that can lead to problems for reservations which span multiple days. Also, your comparisons only examine the value in the first record of the query.  To handle multiple records, you must loop. Keeping date and time in separate columns seems to be adding an unnecessary level of complexity to the logic. Consider changing the database structure. It would greatly simplify things. Only a single query would be required, no cfif's or extra queries.

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should do something to keep qryDate local to your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly, storing the date and time in separate columns is making this task harder than it needs to be IMO. In a reservation system, the two are integrally related. Separating them just makes it a lot harder to perform common tasks, such as checking for conflicts or overlaps (as supported by your recent threads). Unless there is a good reason they must be kept separate, I would recommend restructuring the table and storing reservation date and time in single column.

For example with a structure like this, you could easily check for conflicting reservations in a single query, even ones spanning multiple days:

[image: Reservation table structure]
[image: Reservation table data]

When adding a new record, use an `EXISTS` clause to insert the record only when no conflicting reservations are found:

```
   <!--- example of reservation date/time to check --->
   <cfset requestedStartDateTime = createDateTime(2016, 1, 14, 14, 0, 0)>
   <cfset requestedEndDateTime = createDateTime(2016, 1, 15, 16, 0, 0)>
   ...

   <cfquery result="yourResult" ....>
    INSERT INTO Reservation ( startDateTime, endDateTime, .... )
    SELECT <cfqueryparam value="#requestedStartDateTime#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp">
            , <cfqueryparam value="#requestedEndDateTime#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp">
            , ....
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
          (
            <!--- existing reservation that would overlap --->
            SELECT  reservationID
            FROM    reservation
            WHERE   startDateTime < <cfqueryparam value="#requestedEndDateTime#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp">
            AND     endDateTime > <cfqueryparam value="#requestedStartDateTime#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp">
          )
   </cfquery>
```

You can determine the outcome by examining cfquery's `result` attribute. If the `result.recordcount` is > 0, the new reservation was inserted. Otherwise, you know a conflict was found and can take action accordingly. Tested with CF9/11 and MySQL5.6.

[image: CFQuery Result Structure]

```
   <cfif yourResult.recordCount gt 0>
       SUCCESS: New reservation added 
   <cfelse>
       ERROR: Conflict detected. INSERT failed.
   </cfif>
```

**Update:** If your table contains some sort of auto incrementing column, another option is using the new ID value returned [as part of the "result" structure](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fae.html). If it exists, the insert succeeds. Otherwise, it failed. Note, in older versions like CF9, the ID key names are database specific, ie MySQL - `"generated_key"`. As of CF10+, you can use the generic key name `generatedKey`.

```
   <!--- ID was generated --->
   <cfif structKeyExists(yourResult, "generated_key")>
       SUCCESS: New reservation added 
   <cfelse>
       ERROR: Conflict detected. INSERT failed.
   </cfif>
```

If you absolutely cannot change the table structure, another possibility is to create a [VIEW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28SQL%29) or [COMPUTED COLUMN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (if your database supports it) containing the combined date and time in a single column.  That would at least simplify querying the two values, and allow you to use the technique above to solve your issue. However, while it would simplify the SQL they are not always [SARGable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). So with large datasets they may not perform as well as a single indexed column.

Comment: This works for me and it's way easier than check everything with cfif, also storing date and time in the same column helped. I have one question, what is the best way to protect cfquery before even run Insert? Should that be isDefined or structKeyExist? Thanks one more time.

Comment: Generally, `structKeyExists` is a preferred because it is more precise, but in many cases the net effect is the same.  Keep in mind those two functions verify a variable exists, which is different than being *empty*. For example, a form field might be empty, but still exist on the action page.

Comment: I usually use structKeyExist. I tested this logic where we have to check recordcount but that does not work for me. Record is not inserted in the table but message always indicate that record is inserted. I'm not sure what is wrong with that code?

Comment: I did cfdump on yourResult.recordCount and no matter what always gives me 1. Even if record is not inserted in the table. Do you know what else can be used to check this?

Comment: It worked fine for me with CF11. What version are you using and which dbms?

Comment: CF9 and 5.1.30 dbms.

Comment: 5.1.30 sounds like MySQL. Weird. I just tested with 9.0.2 and MySQL 5.6 and it worked fine there too. Though it did require adding `from dual`.

Comment: I just used my scope id, that helped me to fix this issue. I'm not 100% sure if that is the best way but scope id is [empty] if insert fails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101005/discussion-between-user3023588-and-leigh).

Comment: Couple things. A) You cannot use structKeyExists for the recordCount. That key always exist in the "result" structure, making a structKeyExists test rather pointless ;-).  B) Did you run the example "as is"? It works fine under CF9 or 11 + MySQL 5.6, suggesting either you are using different code or possibly 5.1.3 behaves differently. We would need to see your code to be sure C) Not sure what you mean by "used my scope id".  The RecordCount code should work fine. However, if the table contains an auto increment column, checking the structure for the existence of "generatedKey" would also work.

Comment: C) same as you did with SELECT ROW_COUNT As RowInserted I have done with Select Scope_ID() as RecID. I tried example as is but result was 1 even if insert failed.

Comment: Ohh.. okay.  Like I said above, if your table contains some sort of auto incrementing id, you do not need any extra SQL. CF returns the *new* ID automatically [as part of the "result" structure](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fae.html), if the insert succeeds. For that check, you *can* use structKeyExists.  For MySQL CF9 use:  `<cfif structKeyExists(yourResult, "generated_key")>`.  For CF10+ use the generic key name: <cfif structKeyExists(yourResult, "generatedKey")>` (note the lack of "_").